# Creating common props for styled components

Tags: reactjs

I am new to styled components and can someone help me on how we can have common string/props/base i.e

```
export const MaterialIcon = styled(MIcon)`
    ${props => props.color || props.fill && css`
        color: ${processColor(props.color || props.fill, props.theme)};
    `};
`;


export const Octicons = styled(OctIcons)`
    ${props => props.color || props.fill && css`
        color: ${processColor(props.color || props.fill, props.theme)};
    `};
`;
```

i.e in the above code both `MIcon` and `OctIcons` have same stuff in string

Consider MIcon as importing material icons from react-native

How can I create common

```
  ${props => props.color || props.fill && css`
        color: ${processColor(props.color || props.fill, props.theme)};
    `};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this `emotion` library, it's quite simple to add props. Check [this](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop) link.